# Swift Eureka: Can't dynamically hide/show ButtonRow inside cellUpdate

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, eureka-forms

This is my code for showing and hiding the row. I basically set the hidden attribute as mentioned in the Eureka FAQ. Please let me know if this is the correct way to set the hidden attribute to show/hide the row.

```
    form
    +++ Section("main")
    <<< ButtonRow () { (row: ButtonRow) -> Void in
        row.tag = "sampleRow"
        if self.shouldHide {
            print("hide exampleRow")
            row.hidden = true
        } else {
            print("show exampleRow")
            row.hidden = false
        }
    }
    .cellSetup ({ [unowned self] (cell, row) in
        row.title = "Title Example"
        row.cell.tintColor = .red
    })
    .cellUpdate({ [unowned self] (cell, row) in
        if self.shouldHide {
            print("cellUpdate: hide exampleRow \(self.shouldHide)")
            row.hidden = true
        } else {
            print("cellUpdate: show exampleRow \(self.shouldHide)")
            row.hidden = false
        }
    })
    .onCellSelection({ (cell, row) in
        print("It's Me!")
    })
```

Later in the code, I update the variable `shouldHide` to true or false and call tableView.reloadData(), which does call the cellUpdate block but nothing happens. Could someone please help? Here's my project that you can clone and reproduce this issue. https://github.com/cuongta/testEurekaHideShow

Thanks again!

Comment: you need hide and show when? and another question where you are updating eureka form?

Comment: I need to hide and show when I click on a button, which is already connected to an IBAction. Here's the complete source code: https://github.com/cuongta/testEurekaHideShow/blob/master/testEurekaHideShow/ViewController.swift

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: No, it didn't work. doesn't onCellSelection get called only when the cell is selected.

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Yep, that works! Thanks Reinier! Is evaluateHidden mandatory for hiding a cell or just a force workaround? I don't see it being mentioned in the doc(https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#hiding-using-an-nspredicate) or used in the Sample app... Thanks for the help!

Comment: this is what comments says in the method definition
     **Evaluates if the row should be hidden or not and updates the form accordingly**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to hide a row or even a section in `EurekaForm` is modifying the `.hidden` property and call `.evaluateHidden()` method after that, so to make you code work you need do this modification, your `shouldHide` var is not required for this task

replace the `.onCellSelection` callback method by this one

```
.onCellSelection({ (cell, row) in
                    print("It's Me!")
                    row.hidden = true
                    row.evaluateHidden()
                })
```

## Full Code

```
    form +++ Section("main")
        <<< ButtonRow () { (row: ButtonRow) -> Void in
            row.tag = "sampleRow"
            }
            .cellSetup ({ (cell, row) in
                row.title = "Title Example"
                row.cell.tintColor = .red
            })
            .onCellSelection({ (cell, row) in
                print("It's Me!")
                row.hidden = true
                row.evaluateHidden()
            })
```

## Updated

If you want to hide a cell from any other context you need to get that cell by tag and after that you can modify `.hidden` and calling `.evaluateHidden()` method will be done

```
@IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if let buttonRow = self.form.rowBy(tag: "sampleRow") as? ButtonRow
    {
        buttonRow.hidden = true
        buttonRow.evaluateHidden()
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but it is not removing the whitespace of that buttonRow. I want to know how to remove the whitespace too of that buttonRow because when I show that buttonRow again after hiding it is showing below that whitespace.